# How to render Inequalities in R Shiny SelectInput dropdown list

Tags: r, encoding, shiny, character-encoding

I have created an R Shiny app using the `shinydashboard` package.  I cannot seem to get inequalities or unicode characters to appear in dropdown boxes using the `selectInput` function.  Can anyone help me figure out how to get a greater than or greater than or equal to sign (≥) appear in a dropdown?  Here is an example that demonstrates the issue:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = FALSE,

                   selectInput("Age", "4. Select Age Group:",
                               c("\u2265 6 months" = "_6plus",
                                 "&ge 6 months" = "_6plus2",
                                 "&#8805; 6months" = "_6plus3",
                                 "&#8805; 6months" = "_6plus3",
                                 "6 months - 4 years" = "_6_4"))),

  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs()
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  #addClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, this none of the attempts seems to work.  I'd appreciate any assistance.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `render` option of `selectizeInput` to use HTML code in the choice names:

```
library(shiny)

render <- "
{
  option: function(data, escape){return '<div class=\"option\">'+data.label+'</div>';},
  item: function(data, escape){return '<div class=\"item\">'+data.label+'</div>';}
}"
  
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(
    "age", "Age category", 
    choices = c(
      "&le; 6 months" = 1,
      "6 months - 17 years" = 2,
      "&ge; 18 years" = 3
    ),
    options = list(
      render = I(render)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

After working on this for quite some time, I found one solution, but I would still appreciate suggestions from others.  The only way I've been able to accomplish this is by placing the age categories in a UTF-8 text file, say `agegroups.txt`, reading in the file with the `readr` package, creating a named vector from the read-in tibble, and then using the vector to create the dropdowns.  Here is an example that works:

**Text File:**

```
≥6 months
6 months - 17 years
≥18 years
```

**R Code:**

```
library(readr)
agegroups <- unique(read_csv("d:\\\\agegroups.txt"))
agegroupchoices <- setNames(agegroups$AgeGroups, agegroups$AgeGroups)

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    collapsed = FALSE,
    selectInput("Age", "4. Select Age Group:", agegroupchoices)
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs()
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```